# Graph spokg_test is still is in Provisioning state

Tags: graph, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have created a graph using DSE 5.0 but now the graph is showing error while i am trying to do any operation .
ERROR:-
Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Graph spokg_test is still is in Provisioning state

Even if a i am trying to drop the graph it shows the same error .
DataStaxEnterprise 5.0 uses cassandra 3.0.7 as backend where all graphs vertices and edges are stored . 
I also tried to delete the keyspace from cassandra for this graph , but again while creating the graph with same name it show the error .

Any suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

Three keyspaces are created in Cassandra for each graph, , , and http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/refCassKSandTables.html